# R select rows in dataframe by external vector as index

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data and I want to subset some rows from the table if the name is in the vector `l`.

```
df <-data.frame("Names" = c("TIGIT", "ABCB1", "CD8B", "CD8A", "CD1C", "F2RL1", "LCP1",  "LAG3", "ABL1", "CD2", "IL12A", "PSEN2", "CD3G", "CD28", "PSEN1", "ITGA1"),"1S" = c("5", "6", "8", "99", "5", "0", "1",  "3", "15", "15", "34", "62", "54", "6", "8", "9"), "1T" = c("6", "4", "6", "9", "5", "11", "33",  "7", "8", "24", "34", "62", "66", "4", "78", "44"))
rownames(df) <- df$Names
df <- df %>% select(-"Names") # df I have

l <- c("TIGIT", "CD8B", "CD8A", "CD1C", "F2RL1", "LCP1",  "LAG3", "CD2", "PSEN2", "CD3G", "CD28", "PSEN1") # genes I want to select
```

I want to get the following table in the output.

```
  X1S X1T
TIGIT   5   6
CD8B    8   6
CD8A   99   9
CD1C    5   5
F2RL1   0  11
LCP1    1  33
LAG3    3   7
CD2    15  24
PSEN2  62  62
CD3G   54  66
CD28    6   4
PSEN1   8  78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to filter by the gene names, if you keep them as a column,
instead of making them `rownames`.

The following changes to your code will get you the result you are lookin for.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-data.frame("Names" = c("TIGIT", "ABCB1", "CD8B", "CD8A", "CD1C", "F2RL1", "LCP1",  "LAG3", "ABL1", "CD2", "IL12A", "PSEN2", "CD3G", "CD28", "PSEN1", "ITGA1"),"1S" = c("5", "6", "8", "99", "5", "0", "1",  "3", "15", "15", "34", "62", "54", "6", "8", "9"), "1T" = c("6", "4", "6", "9", "5", "11", "33",  "7", "8", "24", "34", "62", "66", "4", "78", "44"))

genes_to_select <- c("TIGIT", "CD8B", "CD8A", "CD1C", "F2RL1", "LCP1",  "LAG3", "CD2", "PSEN2", "CD3G", "CD28", "PSEN1") # genes I want to select

df <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(Names %in% genes_to_select) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("Names") %>% 
  mutate(across(.fns = as.numeric)) %>% 
  as.matrix()

df
#>       X1S X1T
#>  [1,]   5   6
#>  [2,]   8   6
#>  [3,]  99   9
#>  [4,]   5   5
#>  [5,]   0  11
#>  [6,]   1  33
#>  [7,]   3   7
#>  [8,]  15  24
#>  [9,]  62  62
#> [10,]  54  66
#> [11,]   6   4
#> [12,]   8  78
```

Comment: Dear @Tim I have it as index because it's a matrix which should contain only counts. Thanks

Comment: I see, I changed my answer to transform the `data.frame` to a `matrix` after filtering for the desired rows.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>%
    slice(match(Names, l)) %>%
    column_to_rownames('Names')
```

Answer (score 1):

One line does the job:

```
df[rownames(df) %in% l,]

      X1S X1T
TIGIT   5   6
CD8B    8   6
CD8A   99   9
CD1C    5   5
F2RL1   0  11
LCP1    1  33
LAG3    3   7
CD2    15  24
PSEN2  62  62
CD3G   54  66
CD28    6   4
PSEN1   8  78
```

Or if you have `Names`:

```
df[df$Names %in% l,]
```